# Exception for same data update

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Need help in exception handling.
If I run this UPDATE script once it works, but when I run same script two or more times I receive the following error
    "1 row updated. commited" 
but it is not ok.
I want to receive exception.
"Note:Table is already updated"

```
UPDATE FBTB_TXNLOG
SET txnstageid = '-1',
LOCKED = 'N',
where xrefid = 'FJB1229000056689';
commit;
```

Comment: Add `AND (locked <> 'N' OR txnstageid <> '-1')` to the `WHERE` clause and check how many rows were updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON -- need for dbms_output.put_line()
declare 
  cnt int;
begin
  -- if data exists 
  SELECT count(1)  
  INTO   cnt
  FROM   FBTB_TXNLOG
  WHERE   txnstageid = '-1'
  and  LOCKED = 'N'
  and xrefid = 'FJB1229000056689';

 if (cnt > 0 ) 
 then  
   -- exists: display message
   dbms_output.put_line('Table is already updated');  
 else
   -- let's edit 
   UPDATE FBTB_TXNLOG
   SET txnstageid = '-1',
       LOCKED = 'N',
   where xrefid = 'FJB1229000056689';
   commit;
 end if; 
end;
/
```

Comment: hi, when "if(cnt>0)" is false then "else" part is run,right.again run the script with no changes "if(cnt>0)" is false again, scripts run with no exception.if "if(cnt>0)" is true then it througs exception. please help. thanks again

Comment: That's weird, because it works for me. Are you sure you have the same params in select statement and update statement?

Comment: yes tested,params are same but not the same values.please give different values in select and update statements to falsify the if condition.thanks sir.

Comment: `txnstageid`,`LOCKED`and `xrefid` need to be the same in update and select as above.

Comment: sorry for distrubing you :) please ignore FBTB_TXNLOG table.let discuss with simple HR schema.                                     SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
  cnt INT;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(1)
     INTO cnt
     FROM employees
    WHERE first_name='Steven'
    AND last_name   ='King'
    AND employee_id ='100';
  IF(cnt            >0) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Table is already updated');
  ELSE
     update employees
    SET first_name     ='Steven' ,
      last_name        ='King'
      WHERE employee_id='100';
    COMMIT;
  END IF;
END;

Comment: Got It.thanks sir your spare time for helping.i again realy thank ful to you. realy its a nice place for learners. Taoqir